# Configuring Wireless Static IP through Terminal

Tags: networking, wireless, ip, configure

I try to configure a Wireless Static IP and everything I have found so far are referring to Ethernet connections.
A helpful guide I have found is this one:

http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu-the-proper-way/

So far I have written this in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.108
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

How can I modify it to get a Wireless Static IP?

Edit:

Changed `eth0` to `wlan0`, but when I restarted the network I could not connect to the Internet.

```
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.108
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

My `ifconfig` output after the change was:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:74:9d:e3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10049 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10049 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:923248 (923.2 KB)  TX bytes:923248 (923.2 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:b5:7d:e9:1a:79  
          inet addr:192.168.0.108  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:125998 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:78544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:163553553 (163.5 MB)  TX bytes:9362435 (9.3 MB)
```

Checked my routing(with `wlan0` commented out) and got this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use  Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: Use your wireless interface instead of `eth0`. Give output of `ifconfig`. Now you have set static to your wired link.

Comment: Check your routing by `route -n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface wlan0 is not going to properly connect 192.168.**0**.108 given a gateway of 192.168.**1**.1. One or the other is incorrect. I suggest you check other devices on the same network to verify these details.

Also, any wireless interface requires the name of the network and the WPA key in order to associate. I suggest your */etc/network/interfaces* file be amended to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static  
address 192.168.1.108  
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid <your_network>
wpa-psk <your_key>
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Of course, substitute your verified details above.

Comment: Firstly,does it matter if I use WPA or WPA2 for security?
Secondly,do I need to use '\' if my SSID contains spaces?
Thirdly,does my key have to be in hex or plain decimal?

Comment: WPA2 is preferred as it's more secure. If your SSID contains spaces, use quotes: `wpa-ssid "My Little Router"` Finally, the key needs to be in clear text; that is, whatever the key you entered in the router, exactly.